# Where is the "Store" menu in the Visual Studio 11 Beta?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Where is the "Store" menu in the Visual Studio 11 Beta?  I just downloaded and installed the Ultimate version and there's no "Store" menu like I see in all the [video tutorials](http://www.engadget.com/2012/02/14/microsoft-guide-explains-how-to-submit-windows-8-apps/).

[What I see in my installation](http://screencast.com/t/am0RCkfp)

[What I expect to see](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/02/13/submitting-your-windows-8-apps.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: Wrong version.  Express is further along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a Metro project.

You'll find the menu in `Project` | `Store`